# What does java call the char arrays it stores strings in?

Tags: arrays, string, char

In Java a string literal is stored as number of chars in an array, what is the naming convention of the arrays and the pointers of the String object that points to the arrays in question? Java docs seem to suggest they are named the same, in the following case "data". Quotation from Java doc v 12:

"String str = "abc";

is equivalent to:

char data[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
String str = new String(data);"

I hope that is clearer. I have been looking all over for an answer.

Comment: Why would they be `data1`, `data2` ...? If they're just a member of the object, it would be `someString.data`. Even if they were external of the object, they could be grouped in a `Map` or some other structure.

Comment: It stores them as pointer to the first Character of the string. It does not have a name. Just an address.

Comment: According to the source code for the String class http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java and http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java The variable in the class that holds the data is called value.

Comment: Nice, thanks for sharing the source code.

Comment: Yeah, value looks to be the name they use in the code. It's everywhere in the code(not the comments, the code), not so odd considering it's source code for the string class, but hey. So every String object should have this "private final char value[]". I presume it is of data type char array reference. I am happy to take that as an answer, not sure how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jerry Jeremiah, feel free to post your own answer and I'll delete this and accept your answer.

The char arrays that Java store strings in are called "value".